# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una variable en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito saber como obtener el valor de x luego de ejecutar este código (utilizando Javascript):

```
x = 1; 
if(x < 1) {
   x = 2;
}else if (x >= 1) {
   x = 0;
}else{
   x = 3;
}
```

Comment: saludos, dale en editar y mejora tu pregunta, por que no es clara, aque te refieres con obtenerla?

Comment: Al final `x` value cero.

Answer (score 1):

No he había percatado que pertenecía a javascript tu pregunta

Opción 1

```
alert("Resultado de la variable:"+ x);
```

Opción 2

```js
document.getElementById("variable").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="variable"></p>
```

Opción 3

```html
console.log(x);
```